# Django REST Framework API : How to save/upload images with the name given by user(e.g. username.jpg) at Django server

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, backend, rest

I want to upload image with the name (which is given by user) at Django server through rest API,but i am not be able to find out the solution for this.Please tell me how to upload image with given name.
here is my code(mainly):

**IN API TASK ->URLS:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf import settings
from myapi import views

from django.conf.urls.static import static
#Define API Routes

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'myimage', views.myimageViewSet)  #we have only on viewset


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
   url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**IN  My API**

**1. MODEL**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class myimage(models.Model):
    my_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    my_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/',default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_name
```

**2.SERIALIZERS**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import myimage

class myimageserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =myimage
       fields=('id','my_name','my_image')
```

**3. VIEWS**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import myimage
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import myimageserializer
from rest_framework import filters
import django_filters.rest_framework

class myimageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = myimage.objects.all()  #We use Filters for Ordering so remove order_by part
    serializer_class = myimageserializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering  = ('id','my_name',)
```

**4.ADMIN**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import myimage

admin.site.register(myimage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I changed my code as mentioned below and now its working for me if you have any better solution please suggest here #happycoding**

**1. views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import myimage
from rest_framework import views
from .serializers import myimageserializer
import django_filters.rest_framework
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class myimageView(APIView):
   
    def get(self, request):
        myimagelocal= myimage.objects.all()
        serializer = myimageserializer(myimagelocal, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
  
    def post(self, request):
        myname=request.data['my_image'].name
        myformat=""
        for c in reversed(myname):
            myformat+=c
            if c=='.' :
                break
        myformat=myformat[: : -1]
        request.FILES['my_image'].name=request.data['my_name']+myformat
       
        serializer = myimageserializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**IN API_TASK->URLS:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls,name='admin'),
    path('',include('myapi.urls'))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**IN API_Task->myapi->url**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import myimagedetailsView, myimageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('myimage/', myimageView.as_view(),name='myimageView'),
]
```

**Rest files unchanged**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FileParser` to be able to get your image details in the request data object. I recommend you to follow the example in DRF's [FileParser Example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser)